# how to extract h264 raw video from mov using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I can use MP4Box to extract the h264 track from a mov file:

```
$MP4Box -raw 1 test.mov
$file test_track1.h264
test_track1.h264: JVT NAL sequence, H.264 video, main @ L 30
```

How can i do it by ffmpeg?

I've try with these options but none acts like MP4Box.

```
$ffmpeg -i test.mov -vcodec copy -an -f rawvideo 1.h264
$file 1.h264 
1.h264: data

$ffmpeg -i test.mov -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -vcodec copy -an -f rawvideo 2.h264
$file 2.h264
2.h264: data
```

Comment: I just tried that command line for extracting raw H.264 data and it worked, which is to say that 'file' reported the JVT NAL sequence. What version of FFmpeg are you working from?

Comment: It is on debian 7. The ffmpeg version is `ffmpeg version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-1, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers`

Comment: when i use avconv, it gives same results.

Comment: Chris, I have also used ffmpeg this way with success, but avconv does not have the "-vbsf h264_mp4toannexb" option and the raw file it produces for H.264 does not play for me.  How did you do this with avconv?

Comment: `$ ffmpeg -i test.mov -vcodec copy -f h264 3.h264` worked for me using `ffmpeg` 2.5

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `-f rawvideo` from your command line,

It should be:

```
$ffmpeg -i test.mov -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -vcodec copy -an 2.h264
```

Since I'm learning this is my viewpoint:

There is no need to specify a format, you're already telling ffmpeg the specified format is raw, here:

```
-vbsf h264_mp4toannexb
```